# set different interval for each image

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, fadein, setinterval

I want to make one image pause for 9 secs and the other pause for 3 secs with this simple jquery slideshow

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.fadein2 img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein2 :first-child').fadeOut(2500).next('img').fadeIn(2500).end().appendTo('.fadein2');}, 9000);
});
</script>
```

html

`<div class="fadein" >
<img src="1.jpg" >
<img src="2.jpg">
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [<sup>**this**</sup>****this****<sub>**this**</sub>](http://jsfiddle.net/d64EE/)?

```
function changeBackground() {
    $(".fadein2 img").first().fadeIn("slow", function showNext() {
        var next = $(this).next('img').length ? $(this).next('img') : $(".fadein2 img").first();
        $(this).siblings().fadeOut('slow').delay(3000);
        next.fadeIn("slow", showNext).delay(9000);
    });
}

$(function() {    //    starts when page is loaded and ready
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 0);
})
```

## jsFiddle using just images, not set as background

Comment: yes but i need it to fade the individual images not a background.

Comment: @user2405912 ok, so alter it to suit your needs, that's just an example. You can set it up however you like. The JS pretty much won't change. Just change selectors as needed, set your HTMl and CSS and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure what you want to do, but I think you want this.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/